# Template overload resolution and implicit conversions

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, implicit-conversion

Wanting to try my hand, I recently decided to try and implement a templated complex number class in C++. As a reference I used the C++ 11 standard library implementation, and I came across, a difference between that implementation and mine. It refers to how they overloaded the += operator in their class.

In mine I basically have a single += method, that is able to handle both `Complex<T> += Complex<U>` and `Complex<T> += whatever other type that implicitly converts to T and thus Complex<T>`. For clarification here is the class declaration:

```
template <typename T>
class Complex {
    public:
        constexpr Complex (T=T(), T=T()); // added for clarity

        template <typename U>
        constexpr Complex (const Complex <U>&);
        template <typename U>
        constexpr Complex (Complex <U>&&);
        template <typename U>
        Complex <T>& operator= (const Complex <U>&);
        template <typename U>
        Complex <T>& operator= (Complex <U>&&);

        Complex& operator+= (const Complex<T>&);
        Complex& operator-= (const Complex<T>&);
        Complex& operator*= (const Complex<T>&); 
        Complex& operator/= (const Complex<T>&); 
        Complex& operator++ (void);
        Complex operator++ (int);
        Complex& operator-- (void);
        Complex operator-- (int);

        std::string to_string (void) const;

        constexpr T real (void);
        constexpr T img (void);
        void real (const T&);
        void img (const T&);

    private:
        T _m_real, _m_img;
        template <typename U>
        friend class Complex;
};
```

However in the standard library implementation, they use 2 overloads for `operator+=`, one that takes a `Complex<U>` and another one that takes `T`. Both implementations seem to yield the same behaviour as far as I tested: addition between any two complex types or a complex and another type that implicitly converts to that of the complex's internal.

So, my question is: Is there any reason for a separate `operator+=(T)` other than optimizing away a temporary complex and why  use a nestde `template <typename U>` if all other complex types implicitly convert to Complex?

Comment: `complex< T > & operator+=(const T & t)` adds `t` only to the **Re** part of the complex number. Effectively, `t` is a complex number with **Im** part equal to `0`. Same goes for `complex< T > & operator-=(const T & t)`. You can see for yourself in `complex` header.

Comment: The signature of your from-scalar ctor is missing?  Is there a `=0` missing in a ctor?

Comment: Yeah, i fixed that in the edit. It's in the implementation, didn't add it to the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct Foo {
  operator int()const {
    return 7;
  }
};`
```

You will have problems incrementing by `Foo`, as only one user defined conversion will be called.

As an example:

```
Complex<double> d;
Foo f;
d += f; // fails to compile with your version, compiles with C++ standard one
```

There is another difference.  If we have a class `Bar` that has an `operator Complex<double>() const`, it will fail to work with the C++ standard version.

With your version, it works iff `T` is exactly `double`.

In short, your arguments being implicitly convertible to/from a particular type isn't the same as taking arguments of that type.  Only one user defined conversion can be tried, so if you take `int` types that can convert to `int` are acceptable, and if you take a type that can be made from `int`, not all types that can convert to `int` are acceptable.

Non-user defined conversions are not restricted in the same way.

Comment: Wrong topic, most likely.

Comment: So would you advise against my implementation considering that the standard library's more verbose overloading offers a somewhat more well-defined behavior?

Comment: @vitiv I do not know for certain.  I find the lack of `CanImplicitlyConvertTo<Complex<T>>` overloads in the standard problematic.  I find the lack of `CanImplicitlyConvertTo<T>` overloads in yours problematic.  Both of these become miles easier in C++1y.  Hopefully the standard is based off of actual practical use cases and its decisions where based off of them...  check the history of the `Complex` proposal!

Answer (score 1):

The two interfaces that you are comparing are really:

```
// 1
Complex<T>& operator+=(const Complex<T>&);

// 2
template <typename X>
complex<T>& operator+=(const complex<X>&);
complex<T>& operator+=(const T&);
```

The two differences are that in 2, the overload taking a `complex` is templated on the type of the argument, and that there is an explicit overload that takes the `T` directly. Due to the existing (assuming that you added the missing constructor [*]) conversions both approaches will basically allow the same code to compile, but at an extra cost.

If you only want to add a value to the real part of the complex number, the first design requires the creation of a `Complex<T>` (assuming that you had that constructor, which is not shown), while in the second case no temporary object needs to be created.

Similarly, given as argument a different instantiation of the `complex` type, the implicit conversion would be used in 1 to create a temporary that would then be added, while in the second approach the argument would be bound directly without the need of a temporary.

While this is not important with fundamental types, it can be if the type used to instantiate the template is user defined and expensive to construct/copy. Consider a `BigNum` type that dynamically allocated memory, for example. The temporary would incur a memory allocation and deallocation.

[*] You don't allow default construction or construction with a single argument.

Comment: Forgot to mention in the  post, the Complex<T>(T,T) has T() as a default paramater for the imaginary part so adding a real to my complex does not need explicit construction.

Comment: That being said, if I got the gist of it, the only main difference is that my version has the inherent overhead of the temporaries it creates, which now that I think of, has the potential of being a huge downside for expensive-to-construct objects.